# R vector looping confusion

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I'm learning R and I have tracked down a problem in my code to an expectation of what looping over a vector would do. Here's what I'm confused by--say I've got a numeric vector with two nonconsecutive elements in it.

```
x <- c(1, 3)
```

If I loop through the vector to do something with the values it contains, I am not getting the values. This loop, for example,

```
for (i in x) {
    print(x[i])
}
```

prints out

```
[1] 1
[1] NA
```

but I would expect it to print 1 and 3, rather than 1 and NA.

I know I am misunderstanding something, but I cannot see what. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me clear up my understanding.

Comment: Use `for (i in 1:length(x))`

Comment: Or use `for (i in x) {print(i)}` Right now you're confusing indexing and iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by comment above, the answer is to use the follwing:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){

}
```

What your code does is the following:

First iteration: i set to the first value in x (1), uses i to look up 1st value in x (1).
Second iteration: i set to the second value in x (3), uses i to look up the 3rd value in x (does not exist, so NA).